# Mongo db query for finding object type

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, object, mongodb-query

I've 1000's of users and user data looks like the below.
Some users have the devices as `[{some data}]` (array), some users have devices as `{some data}`, and some users have devices as empty `[]`.

> I need mongodb query to find the userslist with devices `{some data}`.
>   Here is the sample of my users data.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d45ac4"), 
    "username" : "abcd",    
    "devices" : []
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d45df7"), 
    "username" : "efgh",    
    "devices" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5827804ef659a60400e12fcb"),
            "devicetype" : "web"
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d45ae8"), 
    "username" : "efgh",    
    "devices" : {
         "_id" : ObjectId("5951ea8b47abe300046ea26e"),
         "devicetype" : "web"
     }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d45b5b"), 
    "username" : "ijkl",    
    "devices" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59bd2317eeff3200049a2ba6"),
            "devicetype" : "ios"
            "devicetoken" : "1abffaa4419d498b48d0bf982"
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d46102"), 
    "username" : "efgh",    
    "devices" : {
         "_id" : ObjectId("58c433da28841d00040d3cdb"),
         "devicetype" : "web"
     }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d46177"), 
    "username" : "efgh",    
    "devices" : {
         "_id" : ObjectId("59d073d96974d20004a4bb9f"),
         "devicetype" : "web"
     }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d456c9"), 
    "username" : "ijkl",    
    "devices" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59b93dd2e6673c00044cca49"),
            "devicetype" : "ios"
            "devicetoken" : "1abffaa4419d498b48d0bf982"
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fe07bab95708fa18d456f4"), 
    "username" : "abcd",    
    "devices" : []
}
```

Comment: You probably want to check if device array is empty rather than checking its type. Aren't you? Check my answer below.

Comment: Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator like this

`db.collection.find( { "devices" : { $type : "object" } } );`

or

`db.collection.find({ "devices": { $not: { $type: "array" } }})`

Comment: But it is strange it is working for me with type `object`

Comment: `db.collection.find({ "devices": { $not: { $type: "array" } } })` is works well for me, i tried this with date you provided.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

Try one of below query as per your requirement (remove empty objects or keep only empty objects):

```
db.device.find( {$and:[ {devices:{ $type : "object" }},{devices:{$not: { $type: "array" }}}], devices:{$ne:{}}} );

db.device.find( {$and:[ {devices:{ $type : "object" }},{devices:{$not: { $type: "array" }}}], devices:{$eq:{}}} );
```

Check this screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Moreover, please note that you have duplicate keys (`_id`) in your data set which means those data sets are not inserted into your DB. So query will obviously won't give proper results.

**Edit**:

OP removed duplicate keys from data set.

Comment: He wants this `{}` so just object types neither array nor empty array.

Comment: I only need the users list who have devices: { }
no need of devices:[ { ----}], and devices :[]

Comment: @PavankumarDasireddy Got it now.

Comment: @PavankumarDasireddy Updated my answer, please check it.Let me know if that works!

Comment: devices: {} means, devices in object like:
 "devices" : {
         "_id" : ObjectId("5a5325442f001203c39193bd"),
         "devicetype" : "web"
  }

Comment: I understand that, my question is whether you got the desired output from above query (updated answer)?

Comment: No, Fetched 0 record(s)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167617/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-dasireddy-and-rahul-raj).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$type` operator.

Find more detail on this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/